# Is there a way to change the shape of Three.js Orbit Controls?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I love the orbit controls included with Three.js, however, is there a way to modify them to follow the path of an ellipse (well technically an ellipsoid) instead of a circle?

I don't need the ability to zoom or pan, just move the camera in an ellipse with the mouse.

If there is a simpler way to do this without orbitControls I would be happy to try that as well.

Comment: `OrbitControls` maps your input to translation information as it maps to a sphere. You would need to modify (or create your own mapping) where the translation maps to an ellipsoid instead. I would do it by taking the unit vector as projected onto a sphere, and project it onto the ellipsoid instead to obtain the new camera coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

For the shape part (2d motion) i think you can do something like this:

```
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2 
controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/2
```

Which would cause the controls to go around in a circle.

I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve an ellipse though since `OrbitControls` has a lot of encapsulated logic that's not public.